# Laravel passport only works on initial load

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-passport

I have weird situation where in my componentWillMount, I call getUserDetail to my backend and receive data fine using Laravel 5.7's passport feature. I also have a test button that calls getUserDetail on the same file, but that returns 401 Unauthenticated error.

```
getUserDetail() {
    this.props.getUserDetail((response) => {
        if (!response.success) {
            // window.location.href = '/logout';
        }
    });
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.getUserDetail();
    this.getUserDetail();
    this.getUserDetail();
}

handleTestBtnClick() {
    this.getUserDetail();
}
```

[image: Screen shot]

It does look like the header between the success and failed response is different

```
Request URL: http://abc.test/api/userDetails
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 03 Nov 2018 07:10:26 GMT
Server: nginx/1.15.3
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.10
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 57
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6
 Connection: keep-alive
 Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=XDEBUG_ECLIPSE; laravel_token=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%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InhkNlNSbUlJb29WQU02dWtPRWNkMnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoia09xcUhkcWVLanp5Q0xUOEVFOWJXM1BqRG1tZ29DVEJMb2xlWU5iekRoeWtsaWhOZDhFZkNzQUVSNlwvR3JNdmIiLCJtYWMiOiI2MWRiYTBmYTRiMjI5OGE5ODQyMTEyODAwOTA4ZWMwYjFkZGExZjc0ZmE5NjU4OTE2MDQ3ZDQzYzkzZWYzZGEyIn0%3D; rice2_session=eyJpdiI6ImNmN0pMWDZFamg4d1ZoZ3BDQTNxbFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiazR6TUd4UmNBUDA2djhCcnJqMDRnN0pRWWtHTkRXZEJvbm1PQXg0UnQ1S21hV2FCK3FvRzJMSjRRQnhTMnczdiIsIm1hYyI6IjVjZTg1MGYxODFmYzdhOWYxNmZmNGRhMTE5MmRiNWY0ZDZlZWRjNzBmZWFmNzUwNzRjMmRjYzRhYzY1NDE1ZTcifQ%3D%3D
 Host: rice2.test
 Referer: http://rice2.test/dashboard
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36
 X-CSRF-TOKEN: uOOKwiNYh1ZZeYjPo29nbxlojlmW1CvhFKTSmEu5e
 X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
 X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6InhkNlNSbUlJb29WQU02dWtPRWNkMnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoia09xcUhkcWVLanp5Q0xUOEVFOWJXM1BqRG1tZ29DVEJMb2xlWU5iekRoeWtsaWhOZDhFZkNzQUVSNlwvR3JNdmIiLCJtYWMiOiI2MWRiYTBmYTRiMjI5OGE5ODQyMTEyODAwOTA4ZWMwYjFkZGExZjc0ZmE5NjU4OTE2MDQ3ZDQzYzkzZWYzZGEyIn0e=
```

Failed

```
Request URL: http://abc.test/api/userDetails
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 03 Nov 2018 07:10:58 GMT
Server: nginx/1.15.3
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.10
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 56
Accept: */*
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6
 Connection: keep-alive
 Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=XDEBUG_ECLIPSE; laravel_token=eyJpdiI6IlZiUk1aa3VKbng5TVZ0bFlKZ0N4Zmc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOXdjVTlpR1NTQ2hsQk9udGp2UDJ5NmYzSm9FVzd3NXBVNmNzSXhEVCtvdStYSjhwR0FNNldYRzhJQzlZdzNwUkg3anUyVktIczFadzk2OVE0NzBVWENqSkdwRTJwcmhRS2JMZXo5d1lvTzhLWlpjY1BoWG9zRHNJMkVWRHFpWFhOOEdWeG9yYkdselZetWWdNVDMxVHVMMkprbloyaGp2b3JWcU9aMit4QWRCTDhuZlNYam8zMmFWN2VVXC9zSmh0VUxDcFhwbWJRdHNlUUpLYjAxVzZnd0pqaDJPQVpDZFZkK0NaVHh5MzBEZUR6UWpzUXFBNkZSNjNXNXYyNVRsOEUiLCJtYWMiOiI1ZjliOGM1Yzk4YjU4NWI1M2IyZDYzZjlmY2U4M2NkNzEzNzI4MzM5ODNmYmFkZmU0OTE4ZTUxNDA2OTZiZTE5In0%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InhkNlNSbUlJb29WQU02dWtPRWNkMnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoia09xcUhkcWVLanp5Q0xUOEVFOWJXM1BqRG1tZ29DVEJMb2xlWU5iekRoeWtsaWhOZDhFZkNzQUVSNlwvR3JNdmIiLCJtYWMiOiI2MWRiYTBmYTRiMjI5OGE5ODQyMTEyODAwOTA4ZWMwYjFkZGExZjc0ZmE5NjU4OTE2MDQ3ZDQzYzkzZWYzZGEyIn0%3D; rice2_session=eyJpdiI6ImNmN0pMWDZFamg4d1ZoZ3BDQTNxbFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiazR6TUd4UmNBUDA2djhCcnJqMDRnN0pRWWtHTkRXZEJvbm1PQXg0UnQ1S21hV2FCK3FvRzJMSjRRQnhTMnczdiIsIm1hYyI6IjVjZTg1MGYxODFmYzdhOWYxNmZmNGRhMTE5MmRiNWY0ZDZlZWRjNzBmZWFmNzUwNzRjMmRjYzRhYzY1NDE1ZTcifQ%3D%3D
 Host: rice2.test
 Referer: http://rice2.test/dashboard
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36
 X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
 X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6InhkNlNSbUlJb29WQU02dWtPRWNkMnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoia09xcUhkcWVLanp5Q0xUOEVFOWJXM1BqRG1tZ29DVEJMb2xlWU5iekRoeWtsaWhOZDhFZkNzQUVSNlwvR3JNdmIiLCJtYWMiOiI2MWRiYTBmYTRiMjI5OGE5ODQyMTEyODAwOTA4ZWMwYjFkZGExZjc0ZmE5NjU4OTE2MDQ3ZDQzYzkzZWYzZGEyIn0e=
```

-------Update-----

This is the code that I use to call my backe

```
//UserAction
function getUserDetail(callback) {
    return dispatch => {
        userService.getUserDetail()
            .then(
                response => {
                    if (response.data.success) {
                        dispatch({type: userConstants.USER_DATA_RECEIVED, payload: response.data.data});
                    } else {
                        callback({success: false});
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    // user may be logged out from the database.
                    console.log('Logging out because user failed to be authenticated');
                    callback({success: false});
                }
            );
    };
}
// UserService
function getUserDetail() {
    return axios.get('/api/userDetails')
        .then(response => {
            return response;
        })
}
```

Comment: Maybe concurrent requests are updating session data while other requests are still in flight? This comment might be related: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/many-time-401-unauthorized-on-ajax-requests/replies/172913

Comment: Hmmm.. I dont think this is the case because I am not running any concurrent request. I just have a button that triggers the call to my api.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking all four of those requests were being made on page load. I notice your failed request doesn't have an `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header though like the success one does. I'm not sure why that would be if they're both using the same method to make the request

Comment: Yeah....sorry I didnt make it clear. The failed one is when I click the button after everything is loaded. I did realise that too but because Laravel passport handles most of of the magic and it 'should just work', Im not sure how to solve this riddle. I am not sure why the failed request did not have XCRF token. Something seems to be different after page loaded

Comment: Can you include the methods actually making the request? This seems like it's a client side js issue rather than something specific to passport

Comment: Sure can. See above. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. @TravisBritz pointed me to the right direction that it is client side problem.

I blindly added in my main blade file. I saw added because I saw it somewhere on the net.

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
};
```

However, this line was already added in bootstrap.js. So me adding this line overrides that causing the tokens to not be there.